# how to create a handler for this linux timer?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer, handler

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*
This function is called periodically.
The actual functionality has to be provided by yourself **/
void my_handler ( timer_t timerid)
{
    printf("\nHello World\n");
}

int main()
{

 // declare some variables
 timer_t timerid;
 struct itimerspec value;
 struct sigevent sevp;

 // initalize the sigevent variable
 // the memset is necessary to avoid segmentation faults
  memset (&sevp, 0, sizeof (struct sigevent));
  sevp.sigev_notify=SIGEV_THREAD;
  sevp.sigev_notify_function=(void *)my_handler;

 // initialize the timer specification
 // currently the offset and the period is 5 seconds  // you have to adjust this to your actual 
//needs
  value.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
  value.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  value.it_interval.tv_sec = 5;
  value.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

 // create the timer
 timer_create (CLOCK_REALTIME, &sevp, &timerid);
 timer_settime (timerid, 0, &value, NULL);

 // this loop has to be adapted, so that the program ends after some time
 while(1)
 {
  sleep(100);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I have created a timer for calling the task for every 5sec and printing as `hello`. Do i want to create a another timer for another task (for every 10ms) ?? how to create a handler in this case ?? How to calculate a start time and stop time for executing the task ??

Comment: FYI, in the loop you can use `pause()` instead of sleeping.

Comment: how to create a handler ??

Comment: There is an example of how to create a handler in the man page for timer_create.  Alternatively, if you man page doesn't have it, try http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html

Comment: Are you trying to create a second timer?  You can call timer_create() multiple times, just use a separate timerid and sevp.  I'm not sure what you mean by start and stop time.

Comment: You can create another timer with an other signal (SIGEV_USR instead of SIGEV_THREAD, for example), and an other handler. Or you can create a single timer, with a reference timer, counting how many reference time have been elapse, and according this, launch function (a function for 5 unit of time, another one for 200, ....)